# Bootstrap 3 IE8 initial visualisation

Tags: internet-explorer-8, visualization, html5shiv

I am creating a Wordpress theme with Bootstrap 3.
I add html5shiv.js and respond.min.js in head and, now, the theme works in IE8.

When I open the website, for a second and only in IE8, the layout isn't correct and then is perfect.

What is the best practice to fix this initial visualisation problem?

Answer (score 1):

Stop using Ie8, it is dead ....

Comment: 3.2% use IE8, I'd like to fix it

Comment: @andygoestohollywood don't be so mean and unhelpful, even if IE8 is dead there are people that use it. If you work for a company that have to support this useless browser, then you have to support it. I like this question, unfortunately it does not work for me. Thanks to the author of the question anyway.

Comment: If you work for a company that has to support IE8, then tell them IE8 is supported, but expect to see some rendering issues, because IE8 is awful. (and dead).

Answer (score 0):

I solve with a css "respond-fix.css" inside conditional comment with this css code:

```
body{visibility:hidden} @media screen and (min-width:1px){body{visibility:visible}}
```